# Problems with installing SASS React

Tags: reactjs, sass

I want to install SASS to my react app.
I try `yarn add node-sass` my console return error:

`./src/comopnents/Form/Form.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/comopnents/Form/Form.scss)`

`Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.`

I found advice to uninstall `node-sass` and install `sass`. I did it, but then I have got this error:

`../src/comopnents/Form/Form.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/comopnents/Form/Form.scss) To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass. Run npm install node-sass or yarn add node-sass inside your workspace. Require stack:`

- `/Users/madlen/(...)/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js`
- `/Users/madlen/(...)/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js`
- `/Users/madlen/(...)/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js`
- /`Users/(...)/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js`
- /`Users/(...)/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js`
- /`Users/(...)/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js`
- `/Users/(...)/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js`
- `/Users/(...)/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js`

I try to upgrate yarn, add sass-loader, nothing helps

Answer (score 7):

Do this in your package json

```
"node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.49.9",
```

React still asks for node-sass after removing it and replacing with sass so you can alias it like this and now react will use sass

Comment: this worked for me! THANK YOU!
I used `^1.62.0` instead of `^1.49.9`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try updating your project's `react-scripts`, as doing so fixed the issue for me.

I was having the same issue - saw advice elsewhere to switch `node-sass` out for `sass`, and then had the same errors mentioned in the OP. Tried Mark O's solution to alias sass, which worked. However, then I tried setting up absolute imports in my project (with `jsconfig.json` in the way [described here](https://%22react-scripts%22:%20%224.0.3%22,)), and that was mysteriously failing too.

I then realized that my project had a very old version of `react-scripts` for some reason, as it was on 2.x.x. So I swapped `react-scripts` in my `package.json` to be `"react-scripts": "4.0.3",` ran `npm install`, did `npm run start` and now absolute imports work. I then tried using `sass` instead of `node-sass` again and that works too (`npm uninstall node-sass`, then `npm install sass`).

Comment: Yep, updating ``` react-scripts``` worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

try stopping the current development server, and install node-sass again.

Comment: When I did that, I got this error again:


`./src/comopnents/Form/Form.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/comopnents/Form/Form.scss)`

`Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.`

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem. These steps fixed my problem.

- Delete node_modules `rm -rf node_modules`
- Delete package-lock.json `rm package-lock.json`
- Run `npm install` or `yarn install`

I am using;

- node-sass: ^6.0.1
- npm: 7.24.2
- node: v16.13.0